# String keys are faster or slower than tuple keys in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, key

I want to create a Python dictionary with keys are combination from two or more variables, I wonder string combination is better or tuple is better

E.g:

```
a = 1 
b = 2
str_key = str(a)+str(b)
tuple_key = (a,b)
```

`dict[str_key]` or `dict[tuple_key]` which one is better?

Comment: There is the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module. It will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

dict with string keys

```
In [9]: a = {'12': 'test', '23': 'test', '56': 'test', '45': 'test', '34': 'test', '01': 'test', '89'
   ...: : 'test', '67': 'test', '910': 'test', '78': 'test'}

In [10]: % timeit [k for k,v in a.items()]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 µs per loop
```

dict with tuple keys

```
In [14]: b={(0, 1): 'test', (1, 2): 'test', (6, 7): 'test', (5, 6): 'test', (7, 8): 'test', (8, 9): '
    ...: test', (4, 5): 'test', (2, 3): 'test', (9, 10): 'test', (3, 4): 'test'}

In [15]: % timeit [k for k,v in b.items()]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 µs per loop
```

Clearly tuple is the winner